# SQL Server Query : Repeat a t-sql code for an entered period

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, cursor

I have created the following T-SQL code to print some variables that I calculate for an entered period.

My objective now is to print my calculated variables for everyday for the entered period. (Otherwise, i need to repeat my treatment for everyday between the entered dates and then print the variables)

T-SQL query :

```
DECLARE @id INT 
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(20), @date date, 
        @attemptresult varchar(20), @servername varchar(20)  
DECLARE @getid CURSOR
DECLARE @MAX_RES_MXUI1 INT, @MXUI1 INT, @MAX_RES_MXUI2 INT;
DECLARE @dstartDate DATE, @endDate DATE

SET @dstartDate = '03/04/2018';
SET @endDate = '04/05/2018';


SET @MXUI1 = 0
SET @MAX_RES_MXUI1 = 0
SET @MXUI2 = 0
SET @MAX_RES_MXUI2 = 0

SET @getid = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT 
        maxsessionuid, name,  
        attemptdate, attemptresult, 
        servername
    FROM 
        logintracking 
    WHERE
        attemptresult != 'ECHEC' 
        AND attemptdate BETWEEN @dstartDate AND @endDate 
    ORDER BY
        attemptdate

PRINT('DATE, MAXUI1, MXUI2')

OPEN @getid

FETCH NEXT FROM @getid INTO @id, @name, @date, @attemptresult, @servername

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- MXUI1
    IF @attemptresult = 'CONNEXION' and @servername = 'MXUI1'
        SET @MXUI1 = @MXUI1 + 1

    IF @MAX_RES_MXUI1 < @MXUI1
        SET @MAX_RES_MXUI1 = @MXUI1
    ELSE IF (@attemptresult = 'DECONNEXION' OR @attemptresult = 'LOGOUT' OR 
    @attemptresult = 'DELAIDEPASSE') AND @servername = 'MXUI1'
        SET @MXUI1 = @MXUI1 - 1

    -- MXUI2
    IF @attemptresult = 'CONNEXION' AND @servername = 'MXUI2'
        SET @MXUI2 = @MXUI2 + 1

    IF @MAX_RES_MXUI2 < @MXUI2
        SET @MAX_RES_MXUI2 = @MXUI2
    ELSE IF (@attemptresult = 'DECONNEXION' OR @attemptresult = 'LOGOUT' OR 
    @attemptresult = 'DELAIDEPASSE') AND @servername = 'MXUI2'
        SET @MXUI2 = @MXUI2 - 1

    FETCH NEXT FROM @getid INTO @id, @name, @date, @attemptresult, @servername
END

PRINT('NEED TO SHOW EVERYDAY DATE IN THE PERIOD, '+CONVERT(varchar(10),     @MAX_RES_MXUI1)+', '+CONVERT(varchar(10), @MAX_RES_MXUI2))
CLOSE @getid
DEALLOCATE @getid
```

Query result:

```
DATE    MAXUI1    MXUI2
---------------------------    
NEED TO SHOW EVERYDAY DATE IN THE PERIOD,11, 15
```

Desired result:

```
DATE          MAXUI1    MXUI2
-----------------------------
03-04-2018      11       15
04-04-2018      13       19
05-04-2018      29       15
...
```

Comment: what is a `treatment`?

Comment: In your cursor you set lots of variables, but i dont seen any print statements for these variables. In other words, you are missing the print statements

Comment: I'd create a stored procedure with your code. Then create a table to write in the results. Then use a SQL-Server-Job (depending on your version) or an OS-Task to execute your SP regularly.

Comment: @GuidoG i print MAX_RES_MXUI1 & MAX_RES_MXUI2 contents just before the cursor's close

Comment: Are you asking how to detect that `@date` has changed and, if so, print and reset the accumulated counts? Might there be missing dates, e.g. no data for dates over a weekend?

Comment: Why aren't you printing anything inside the cursor-loop?

Comment: @HABO yes exactly

Comment: @TabAlleman i need to check that the date has changed ... have you an idea how i could do this ?

Comment: Anass, where is that print command ? I dont see it

Comment: @GuidoG it's PRINT('NEED TO SHOW EVERYDAY DATE IN THE PERIOD, '+CONVERT(varchar(10),     @MAX_RES_MXUI1)+', '+CONVERT(varchar(10), @MAX_RES_MXUI2))

Comment: You need to keep track of the date of the previous row, if any. `declare @PreviousRowDate as Date = NULL;` before the loop and in the loop `if @PreviousRow is NULL set @PreviousRowDate = @Date;` to initialize the previous row date, then detect the date change with `if @PreviousRowDate != @Date begin print ... ; select @PreviousRowDate = @Date, @MaxUI1 = 0, @MaxUI2 = 0; end;` which resets the date and counts after printing. Add a last `print` after the loop. It does nothing about missing dates, i.e. dates with no data, nor does it scrap the whole cursor and loop for a set-based solution.

Comment: Aside: If you search SO for `[tsql] missing dates` you'll find various questions and answers showing how to fill in "missing" dates for data sets that don't have rows for every date.

Comment: Anass, you print that outside the loop. So it can only be printed once

Comment: @HABO Good idea, it seems to work well, thanks for ur help